# SAS: Select string with blank at the end

Tags: string, oracle, sas

I have a problem while selecting data from an Oracle table. Some values are `R`, `RJ`, and so on. However when I run the following query I just get `RJ`:

```
proc sql noprint;
    SELECT col
    FROM myoracletable
    WHERE col IN('R','RJ')
    ;
quit;
```

So I checked the value `R` at Oracle:

```
select distinct rawtohex(col) as col
from myoracletable;
```

The result for `R` is `5220`. So the string is `R[blank]`. I modified my SAS program like this:

```
proc sql noprint;
    SELECT col
    FROM myoracletable
    WHERE col IN('R ','RJ','5220'x)
    ;
quit;
```

However the entries with `R` are still not selected.

How can I solve this issue without trim or compress the string?

Comment: add `'R '` into the list of strings you're checking for?

Comment: Yes, you can see `R ` in the last query.

Comment: Are you sure `4B20` corresponds to `R `? I get `5220` when I run `SELECT RAWTOHEX('R ') FROM dual;`. `K ` is what gives me `4B20`. What happens if you do `dump(col)` as well as `rawtohex` for your suspected `R ` rows?

Comment: why don't you use `trim(col) in IN('R','RJ')` ?

Comment: @Plirkee Presumably because there's an index on the column.

Comment: You are right, it results in `5220`. However in SAS it also does not work. `dump()` gives me `Typ=1 Len=2: 82,32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS uses only fixed length strings and strips trailing blanks to make it work. So it looks like SAS is pushing `'R'` instead of `'R '` into the database when it converts your query for you.

You need to write the Oracle query directly instead. So instead of using implicit syntax like:

```
libname myora oracle ... schema=myoraschema ... ;
proc sql ;
SELECT col
  FROM myora.mytable
  WHERE col IN('R ','RJ')
;
```

You should use explicit syntax like this:

```
libname myora oracle ..... ;
proc sql ;
connect using myora ;
select * from connection to myora 
(SELECT col
  FROM myoraschema.mytable
  WHERE col IN('R ','RJ')
 )
;
```

The long term solution is to fix the Oracle table to NOT store trailing blanks. You might need to redefine the variable as VARCHAR(2) instead of CHAR(2).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour within SAS itself:

```
data have;
input mystr :$2.;
cards;
R
RJ
;
run;

proc sql;
select mystr from have where mystr in ('R', 'RJ');
quit;
```

This selects both values. So one option might be to run an initial query to copy part of the Oracle table into a temporary dataset in your SAS work library, then run another query on that.

You might also get different results if you use a pass-through query to access your Oracle table, but I can't test that.